# Overwrite a single line in a text file

Tags: perl, sed, awk, grep

I am looking for a safe and reliable way to overwrite ONE line in a text file. I don't care if it's using sed, grep, perl whatever. It just needs to be portable and reliable. Specifically what I am trying to do is replace the value of a variable I have saved in a text file at runtime. Let's say I have a file named variables.txt which contains a line that reads userName=stephen. Let's say my program wants to change the userName to frank. Here's what I've come up with using sed:

`sed -i '' 's/userName.*/userName=frank/' variables.txt`

The concern I have with this is that I've read that on some versions of sed using the '-i' switch without specifying a backup file could cause the command to fail or risk possible file corruption. Not an option. What do you guys think?

### Edit

For those asking where I read about command failure and file corruption. The manpage for my version of sed recommends against providing an empty value for the -i switch as well as take a look at the comments on [this page here](http://joemaller.com/823/quick-note-about-seds-edit-in-place-option/):

> It seems that some versions of sed require the argument after -i and others do not. With GNU sed version 4.1.x, it seems that the -i does not require an argument and specifying an empty argument after it actually fails.

It sounds like the unanimous recommendation is to provide a backup file and then delete it after the command completes. However I'm still concerned about this solution since my version of sed doesn't even support the --version switch. My primary concern here is that the solution is both reliable and portable.

Comment: "[…] could cause the command to fail or risk possible file corruption" Can I ask where did you read that?

Comment: _My primary concern here is that the solution is both reliable and portable_, you say. Well, just pass an extension to the `-i` flag! AFAIK _all_ sed versions support this option with a value. Even my limited BSD sed (from Mac OS X) supports it. If you pass the parameter for `-i`, you get both the portability and the safety!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
t=`tempfile`
sed -e 's/userName.*/userName=frank/' variables.txt >$tempfile
cp $tempfile >variables.txt
rm $tempfile
```

you can also use `mv` but that won't preserve file rights

if tempfile is not available then use some other method (`$$`.bak) to create the filename.

Answer (score 1):

As long as you don't run on windows, sed -i is as safe as anything. Even if the machine crashes mid-process, variables.txt will either have the old content or the new content -- it should never be missing or corrupt.

Answer (score 1):

*The concern I have with this is that I've read that on some versions of sed using the '-i' switch without specifying a backup file could cause the command to fail or risk possible file corruption.*

Where have you read it?

It is not strictly true: this is not an usual problem in sed *but* all programs (including sed) can fail and in very unlikely situations corrupt data. So you should not be *too* afraid of data corruption with sed.

Anyway, why do you not use `-i` with an extension (such as `-i.bak`) for granting more safety? In any case you can erase the backup file with `rm`...

Answer (score 0):

You could copy variables.txt to variables.txt.bak before running the command if you wanted to keep a backup.   Or go the other way around:

```
sed  's/userName.*/userName=frank/' variables.txt > variables.txt.fixed
if [ $? -eq 0 ]
then 
   cp variables.txt.fixed variables.txt 
fi
```